# Chang PreFix for Ontology

Tags: owl

I use protege 4 to merge 2 ontology sucessful and save as Onab.owl. In this file, I don't know how to change URI of ontology by OWL API. Could you help me use OWL API to change it
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can get and set the prefix name using methods of the org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.DefaultPrefixManager class. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SetOntologyID` instance with the new IRI you want and apply it to the ontology:

`manager.applyChange(ontology, setOntologyID());`

Then save the ontology, its IRI will have been changed.